# How to get product custom option value using beforeaddtocart plugin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

How do I get the product custom option value in beforeAddtocart plugin method? I am using below function for this.

```
public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo=null)  {

$product_id = $productInfo->getId();

 }
```

I get product id, SKU but am not able to get what product option I am trying to add before add to cart.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also try to get requestinfo object but from this i can only get qty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
```

> // get cart items

```
$items = $cart->getItems();
```

> // get custom options value of cart items

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
    $customOptions = $options['options'];
    if (!empty($customOptions)) {
        foreach ($customOptions as $option) {
            $optionTitle = $option['label'];
            $optionId = $option['option_id'];
            $optionType = $option['type'];
            $optionValue = $option['value'];
        }
    }
}
```